# jQuery store input element

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am making an angularjs app, and I am checking all clicks on the document:

```
  $(document).click(function(event) {

    if(event.target.nodeName == "INPUT") {

        // get and store the element itself

    }
  });
```

And later on I want to trigger keyevent in order to change the value of the input element

```
var findInput = function (element) {
    return element.find('input');
};

var triggerKeyDown = function (element, keyCode) {
    var inputEl = findInput(element);
    var e = $.Event('keydown');
    e.which = keyCode;
    inputEl.trigger(e)
};
```

I've tried multiple times to extract the element from the event using "target" and "toElement" members of the event structure.
So any idea how to do this

Comment: Can you show us the code that calls `triggerKeyDown`?

Comment: At the moment it's nothing special, just a controller that calls triggerKeyDown(inputElement, 83);
Note that inputElement at the moment I am passing event.target from the first snippet of code and 83 is random value

Answer (score 1):

If you're passing `event.target` into `findInput`, as you say in the comment above, then that's your problem.  You need a jQuery object to use `find()`.  Try changing that function to this...

```
var findInput = function (element) {
    return $(element).find('input');
};
```

Comment: This didn't work also :/
But I've managed for it to work someway. I just did "element.value+=keycode" which does the job of filling the input element. But is this the correct way, cuz it doesn't look clean, and what if I try to send some other keycodes, like backspace etc..